# I have created an acf repeater for woocommerce product category now how can I display the repeater data in a specific page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object(); ?>
<?php if(have_rows('category_image',$queried_object->term_id)):?>
    
 <?php while(have_rows('category_image',$queried_object->term_id)):
             the_row();
            $gallery_image=get_sub_field('image');
           
           echo $gallery_image['url'];
            
           ?>

 <p><?php echo the_sub_field('description');?></p>

<a href="<?php echo $gallery_image['url']; ?>" data-lg-size="1024-800">
        <img alt="img2" src="<?php echo $gallery_image['url']; ?>" />
    </a> 


<?php endwhile;?>




   
   
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<h6 class="text-center">No thing found from the backend </h6>
<?php endif;?>
```

the above is my code and its displaying the else part only I have inserted the data from the backend

Comment: Tip: don't put greetings in your post - especially in the title. Please capitalise properly start of sentences and proper nouns (brand or product names, etc.). Indent your code properly and remove multiple blank lines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching ACF field value for taxonomy is little different then normal post. In post you can directly pass ID and it will work. But for taxonomy you need to pass taxonomy slug also like `product_cat_1234`. So, in your case, in `have_rows()` you need to pass `'product_cat_'. $queried_object->term_id` instead of `$queried_object->term_id`.

Reference: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/#get-a-value-from-different-objects

Comment: thank you soo much respected Nilambar Sharma Sir...you have done it .its working now thank you soo much for your precious time